# Default order of records returned by cursor was not same for mobile & tablet

Tags: android

I wrote a select query to access set of records from database by setting null for the argument '`orderBy`' in the `query()`. I found that order of records returned by `query()` method when I run the application in mobile is completely different when I run the same sample application in tablet.

My Query:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(true, tableName, downloadQueueTableColumnNames, selection, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Here, in the query `orderBy` field is null.

I hope someone to explain the reason behind this...

Comment: I am not an SQL expert. But as far as I know an sql query does not always return query results in the same order, so to be sure you get the right order use orderBy.

Comment: Would you mind to tell us how the data records are fed into the databese, amongst a few other details which might help?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't ordering the results, they can be returned in any order.  The same device doesn't have to give the same order if you call it twice in a row.  If you want it in the same order every time, you must use an order by.